# Expo Install/Uninstall

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, jsx

I'm trying to install expo but it shows me this message

> npm ERR! code EACCES 
> npm ERR! syscall mkdir 
> npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli 
> npm ERR! errno -13 
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' 
> npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli'] { 
> npm ERR!   errno: -13, 
> npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', 
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir', 
> npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' 
> npm ERR! } 
> npm ERR!  
> npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system. 
> npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user 
> npm ERR!  
> npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the 
> npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running 
> npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

I had expo installed before and I was trying to start an app over, so I am sure I may have touched something I shouldn't have. I'm a newbie, so any help would be appreciated!

Tried to uninstall VSC, but to no avail. I'm a bit stuck!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to install globally, but you are not using a system administrator account so you don't have permission to do that.

The [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/installation/) says that to start an app you should:

> ```
> npx create-expo-app --template
> ```

The other commands in the documentation also use `npx`, including the CLI:

> ```
> npx expo
> ```

`npx` **won't** try to install things globally, and is the recommended way to install and run applications from npm.

Presumably you are following some other documentation which is predates `npx` and is trying to install globally. Don't do that. Use the modern approach.